# Android app getting NullPointerException after enabling Progurad

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Am getting NullPointerException after enabling the Progurad.

In the application am using dependency called "**com.github.igalata:Bubble-Picker:v0.2.4**". After adding this dependency am getting the NullPointer exception when try to use.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 4318
 Process: com.manoramaonline.week, PID: 20029
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.a.d.l.a(World.java:198)
 at org.a.d.d.a(ContactManager.java:108)
 at org.a.b.a.a.a(BroadPhase.java:187)
 at org.a.d.d.a(ContactManager.java:152)
 at org.a.d.l.a(World.java:540)
 at com.igalata.bubblepicker.physics.Engine.move(Engine.kt:129)
 at com.igalata.bubblepicker.rendering.PickerRenderer.onDrawFrame(PickerRenderer.kt:72)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

**I tried**

- -keep class com.github.** { *; }
- -keep class com.igalata.bubblepicker.** { *; }
- -keep interface com.igalata.bubblepicker.** { *; }
- -keep enum com.igalata.bubblepicker.** { *; }
- -keep class com.github.igalata.** { *; }
- -keep interface com.github.igalata.** { *; }
- -keep enum com.github.igalata.** { *; }
- -keep class  com.igalata.bubblepicker.physics.Engine.move.** { *; }
- -keep class  com.igalata.bubblepicker.rendering.PickerRenderer.onDrawFrame.** { *;
  }

but not working

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add below to your Proguard file:

> -keep public class com.igalata.bubblepicker.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know:

```
-keep class com.igalata.bubblepicker.**
-dontwarn com.igalata.bubblepicker.**
```